# center a text inside a div

Tags: html, css

i would like to know how could i center my text inside a div. in my code this isn't work will for every p-tag, cause text length are not the same.

HTML:-

```
<div class="textBlock">
  <p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
#content .textBlock {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 min-height: 160px;
}

#content .textBlock p {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 font-size: 28px;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 font-weight: 100;
 padding: 0 5%;
 line-height: 34px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what all the other code is for if you're only aligning text?

```css
.textBlock {
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 160px;
}

.textBlock p {
 font-size: 28px;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 line-height: 34px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em; 
}
```

```html
<div class="textBlock">
  <p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's right, it's the absolute positioning that causes the problem. Not sure if this is the answer though; what if the OP does need the absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0):

please Try this one:

Html:

```
<div class="textBlock">
  <p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.textBlock {
 text-align: center;

    background-color:gray;
}

.textBlock p {
 font-size: 28px;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 line-height: 34px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em; 
    color:white;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/r55t4wyr/2/)